# Should I add a custom back-end to my Next.js project?

Tags: javascript, software-development, node.js

I have a fully-running Express back-end from my previous project. It relies heavily on `route->middeware->endpoint` pattern. I chose Next.js for my new project as it offers `SSR/SSG` out of the box. Having created a new Next.js project, now I have to make a critical decision: adding my Express app as a custom server or use Next.js's default server (with directory based routing). After reading [Next.js doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) and some other resources, I am comparing the pros and cons of each, and some questions emerged too.

**If I add my custom express server:**

1. ✓ Availability of wide range of packages/libraries
2. ✓ Easy usage of middlewares (no customization needed)
3. ✘ Lose 'Automatic Static Optimization'( I didn't understand)
4. ✘ Problems with SSR / SSG ( -? I am not sure)
5. ✘ Lose directory based routing (this is ok)
6. ✘ Unable to host on vercel (this is ok)

**If I keep default Next.js server:**

1. ✓ Host on vercel
2. ✓ Automatic Static Optimization ( I didn't understand)
3. ✘ I have to transform the routing system to directory based approach
4. ✘ Some packages stop working or need replacemant
5. ✘ Need to create a custom middleware handler

I might have missed some important points above. In short, which one should I do? I want a well-explained answer from someone who tried both ways.

Comment: This is not asking for a software recommendation, it's about chosing two developing methodologies and therefore off-topic here.

Comment: Where should I post it?